# XCode 7: Unable to Convert OCUnit to XCTest

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, xctest, ocunit

I upgraded the XCode to 7.0 and ran into compilation issues. 
XCode asked me to convert my test target to use XCTest and I followed the wizard screen. 
I'm unable to find any test targets and cannot finish converting.

Does any one know how to fix this ?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have selected the **scheme** of your test target (in the top-left scheme selector), then select Edit -> Convert -> To XCTest... 
This will make Xcode recognize the appropriate target.