# #import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h> not found

Tags: ios

```
#import<SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>
```

*Framework not found while working with "authorization.net"*

Comment: Please make it specific, Can you add little more contents ?

Comment: Can you check this answer ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354891/xcode-sentestingkit-not-found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354891/xcode-sentestingkit-not-found)

Comment: Can you please help a little bit detail.

Comment: tell me what exactly u r doing and how this error come?

Comment: I am converting authorization.net sample files to my project while i am getting this error.

Comment: i am not found any framework in x code like this

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7 the path for this framework is as following but this framework has been depreciated so you need to convert to  `XCTest`.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/MigrationFrameworks/SenTestingKit.framework
```

**UPDATE**
Scheme  Editor option in Xcode 7

[image]

Comment: While i am converting it shows no files how to add files in the xcl test,AND what files i need to add please give me a bit clarification

Comment: Check these links 1.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/A2-transitioning_ocunit_to_xctest.html 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707166/xcode-7-unable-to-convert-ocunit-to-xctest

Comment: I refer this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/A2-transitioning_ocunit_to_xctest.html,and i don't have option (click for scheme editor menu)in my project.

Comment: The target option shown next to stop button is you scheme editor menu. I have attached a screenshot in my answer.